# Why does relativedelta with positive arguments return a date in the past?

Tags: python, python-dateutil, relativedelta

I have some trouble to understand the behavior of dateutil.relativedelta.
I understand that relativedelta could return past dates if I use negative arguments as specified in [relativedelta doc](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html).

However, when I provide positive parameters, I expect that it always return a date in the future... that seems legit right?

My use case is the following : we are Tuesday, it is 8:35. I want to get the date of the closest Monday and Tuesday at 6:00.

Here what I did. The first result seems correct to me, while the second one is wrong.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 8, 35, 23, 786349)

>>> from dateutil import relativedelta
>>> now.weekday()
1

>>> now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=0, hour=6, minute=0) # should give a time in the future
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 5, 6, 0, 23, 786349)  # here this is correct, in the future

>>> now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1, hour=6, minute=0) # should give a time in the future
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 6, 0, 23, 786349)  # but this is in the past / I would expect result (2016, 12, 6, 6, 0, 23, 786349)
```

So , am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's in the doc:

Starting with, about `weekday`:

> These instances may receive a parameter N, specifying the Nth weekday, which could be positive or negative (like MO(+1) or MO(-2). Not specifying it is the same as specifying +1.

So by passing `1`, it's like you're passing `(1, 1)`

Then, continuing on the doc, on the 7th dot of `behavior of operations with relativedelta`:

> Notice that if the calculated date is already Monday, for example, using (0, 1) or (0, -1) won’t change the day.

So the 29th of November is already a Tuesday, and you're asking for a Tuesday.

So nothing changes.

Comment: You're correct, the seventh point explains it all. This is the behavior by design.Thanks for this input which explains everything. It was in the doc and I missed it.

Comment: Actually, you're answer makes more sense and answers the question in my title. So I'm marking it as the accepted answer finally, event hough I'm using the trick from @Bryan answer.

Answer (score 3):

So according to your initial date, you're actually at 8AM, but you're targeting 6AM by using the `hour` param, if you're trying to increment one hour, you should use `hours` and `minutes` respectively

```
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 3, 5, 41, 763818)

>>> now.weekday()
1

>>> now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1, hour=1)
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 1, 5, 41, 763818) # Notice how it's in the past

>>> now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1, hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 29, 4, 5, 41, 763818) # Notice how it's one hour in the future

>>> n + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1, hour=6, minute=0, weeks=1)
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 6, 6, 0, 41, 763818)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bryan, but the result is not the one I expect (next Tuesday, aka 2016 Dec. 6th).

What you did here was to 'add' one hour to the current time. But I want the next 'available' Tuesday at a given hour.

Comment: Does using weeks=1 get you to where you're looking for? ```now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=1, hours=1, weeks=1)```

Comment: Yes, that fixes my first example, but breaks the second one (it gives a result too far in the future).

Comment: Ok, so I think I misunderstood ya in the beginning, you're looking to be exactly at 6 on the dot, one week from now, as I updated at the end of the code in the answer. Is that correct?

Comment: It works for the first example (weekday=1) but breaks on weekday=0 : 

>>> now + relativedelta.relativedelta(weekday=0, hour=6, minute=0, weeks=1)
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 6, 0, 23, 786349)

Comment: The first one should return datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 5, 6, 0, 23, 786349) ... Here, using `weeks` forces an additional timedelta.

Comment: @Tanzaho Use `weekday=rrule.TU(+2)` for next Tuesday, I believe. Don't mess around with `weeks`.